# JavaFX Table view using MySQL database 'No content in table'

Tags: mysql, javafx

I am new to JavaFX. I develop an JavaFX application. I want to show data from MySQL database in TableView.
When I add data from JavaFX, data is perfectly stored in database, but it shows 'No content in table' in tableview. There is no error in my code, I could not find where I made the mistake. I am using Eclipse IDE.

This is Customer class:

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Customer {

private final StringProperty pname;
private final IntegerProperty pphno;
private final StringProperty paddress;

public Customer(String pname,int pphno,String paddress){
     this.pname = new SimpleStringProperty(pname);
     this.pphno = new SimpleIntegerProperty(pphno);
     this.paddress = new SimpleStringProperty(paddress);
}

public StringProperty getpname() {
    return pname;
}

public IntegerProperty getpphno() {
    return pphno;
}

public StringProperty getpaddress() {
    return paddress;
}

}
```

This is Cust.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="575.0" prefWidth="760.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" fx:controller="application.CustController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="tbl_cust" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="249.0" prefHeight="315.0" 
prefWidth="730.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="tcol_name" prefWidth="235.0" text="Name" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="tcol_phno" prefWidth="223.0" text="Phone Number" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="tcol_add" prefWidth="271.0" text="Address" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <VBox layoutX="37.0" layoutY="72.0" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="169.0" spacing="30.0">
         <children>
            <Label text="Name" textFill="#a86905">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Georgia Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" text="Phone Number" textFill="#9e5f02">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Georgia Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="27.0" text="Address" textFill="#a4450a">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Georgia Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <VBox layoutX="220.0" layoutY="79.0" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="223.0" spacing="25.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="txt_name" />
            <TextField fx:id="txt_phno" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="txt_add" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="35.0" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <VBox layoutX="559.0" layoutY="56.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="156.0" spacing="25.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="btn_save" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="105.0" 
text="Save" textFill="#2d8d07">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Impact" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btn_update" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" 
prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="105.0" text="Update" textFill="#0a85d7">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Impact" size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btn_del" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="35.0" mnemonicParsing="false" 
prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="105.0" text="Delete" textFill="#c91c1c">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Impact" size="23.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <Label layoutX="212.0" layoutY="6.0" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="307.0" text="         
Customer Details" textFill="#2e66ae">
         <font>
            <Font name="Impact" size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is CustController class:

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class CustController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TableView<Customer> tbl_cust;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Customer, String> tcol_name;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Customer, Integer> tcol_phno;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Customer, String> tcol_add;

@FXML
private TextField txt_name;

@FXML
private TextField txt_phno;

@FXML
private TextField txt_add;

@FXML
private Button btn_save;

@FXML
private Button btn_update;

@FXML
private Button btn_del;

private String query, cname, cphno, cadd;
DataAccessObj dao;

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    dao = new DataAccessObj();
    
    btn_save.setOnAction(e->{
        insertNewCustomer();
    });
    
    refreshTable();
}

private void initTable() {
    tcol_name.setCellValueFactory(cell->cell.getValue().getpname());
    tcol_phno.setCellValueFactory(cell->cell.getValue().getpphno().asObject());
    tcol_add.setCellValueFactory(cell->cell.getValue().getpaddress());
}

private void refreshTable() {
    initTable();
    query = "select a.Name, a.Phno, a.Address from customer ordered by a.Name";
    tbl_cust.setItems(dao.getCustomerData(query));
}

private void insertNewCustomer() {
    cname = txt_name.getText();
    cphno = txt_phno.getText();
    cadd = txt_add.getText();
    
    query = "insert into customer values('"+cname+"', '"+cphno+"', '"+cadd+"');";
    dao.savedata(query);
    
    txt_name.setText("");
    txt_phno.setText("");
    txt_add.setText("");
    
    refreshTable();
}

}
```

This is DataAccessObject class:

```
package application;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class DataAccessObj {

private DBConnection database = new DBConnection();
private ResultSet rs;
private PreparedStatement ps;
private Connection connect;

public DataAccessObj() {
    
}

public void savedata(String query) {
    try {
        connect = database.getConnection();
        ps = connect.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        database.close(connect, ps, null);
    }
}

public ObservableList<Customer> getCustomerData(String query){
    ObservableList list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        connect = database.getConnection();
        ps = connect.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            list.add(new Customer(rs.getString(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getString(3)));
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
}
```

I am trying to get customer details from database. Database is connected to the javafx and it stores data from javafx but doesn't show data in javafx tableview.

Comment: You should compare the naming convention from here. You are doing the models wrong
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm

Comment: You need to find out if it is a database retrieval issue (for example by printing / debugging `getCustomerData(String)` ) or JavaFx issue.

Comment: java naming conventions, please

Comment: Verify that the list you get from `dad.getCustomerData(query)` is not empty.